# While loop practice

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a while loop to change the `background-color` of some `h1`' s.
I know that there can be only one `H1` on the page but is not what i am try to practice.
The code that I wrote works but when I open the console I still get an error.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>While loop</title>

  <style>
    .red{
      color:red
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="red">heading01</h1>
  <h1>heading02</h1>
  <h1 class="red">heading03</h1>
  <h1>heading04</h1>
  <h1 class="red">heading05</h1>


  <script>
    function changeColor(){
      const heading = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
      let i = 0;
      while (i <= heading.length){
        if (!heading[i].classList.contains("red")){
          heading[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
        }
        i++;
      }
    }

    changeColor();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`index1.html:27  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList') at changeColor (index1.html:27:25) at index1.html:34:5`

Can anyone tell me why it is giving me that error?
Thank you.

I tried to go step by step with a `console.log()` to see what is happening.

Also I tried it with a For Of loop and that works with no errors.

Comment: You can have as many `<h1>` elements as you want.

Comment: And it should be `i < heading.length`; when `i` is equal to the length, that's past the end of the list.

Comment: `while (i <= heading.length)` will run your loop's body twice. Once with `i == 0` and once with `i == 1`. Thus, you are trying to access `headings[1]` which returns `undefined` as there is only one element in `headings` which is at index `headings[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is

```
while (i <= heading.length){ ... }
```

instead of

```
while (i < heading.length){ ... }
```

In almost every programming languages, array indexes starts with 0 and this is the case with JS.

If you console.log the array of headings you will see that you have 5 elements identified with indexes from 0 to 4

```
NodeList(5) [ h1.red, h1, h1.red, h1, h1.red
 ]
​
0: <h1 class="red">​
1: <h1 style="background-color: lightgreen;">​
2: <h1 class="red">​
3: <h1 style="background-color: lightgreen;">​
4: <h1 class="red">
​
length: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the indexing on the while loop. If you have a condition that `i` should keep increasing whilst it is smaller than or equal to the array length. You end up with the last value of `i` being the array length.

If you have arr=['a','b','c'], the indices or [0,1,2] and `arr.length` is 3. So `arr[arr.length]` is `arr[3]` which is undefined.

In this case should be `while (i < heading.length)` so you stop the loop when `i` equals the index of the last element.

Comment: Thanks! 
i don't get the error anymore. I was not looking at `(i <= heading.lenght)`. 
Was looking at  ```if (!heading[i].classList.contains("red")){
          heading[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
        }```
because of the error message `(reading 'classList')`